# Xbox HDD Account vs XBoxLive Account

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I started playing on an xbox 360 that was not connected to the internet and created a local profile, figuring that I could get around to associating that local account with my xbox live account at a later time (which i have used in the past on the PC, just not a console).

However, it seems that there is no way to make that profile associate with an existing xbox live account. I only have the option to create a new account, or download an existing one.

Am I not going to be able to use my old xbox live profile, if I want to keep the saved games and achievements from my local account? Basically I just want the saved games from the local account accessible from the xbox live account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue you had, and after talking to an XBOX rep they told me that i was unable to merge accounts, and i had to choose one.

Comment: Correct, profiles cannot be merged.